# setAnimation on textView has no effect

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm working on application, and I have an `Activity` where I have to show a `TextView`.

Initially the `TextView` is invisible, but when I have to make it visible I set an animation before. The animation works fine on Alcatel One Touch API 17, HTC One X API 17 and Samsung S3 Neo API 19 but on the Nexus 5 API 23 it still uses the default animation while being visible (fade in).

Is there any reason for that to happen? This is the code I use:

```
myTextView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.come_in_from_left));
myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Edit**

I just noticed that when im not on debugger the animation don't work at all on all the devices !!! it look like i need to keep my devices connected to `ADB` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolve it , there was two issues :

**First**

My `TextView` was inside a `RelativeLayout` which has a `LinearLayout` as parent,     the attribute `andoid:animateLayoutChanges` was first mentioned in the `RelativeLayout`,i moved it inside `LinearLayout`.

**Second**

As **mreza sh** suggested to me , i replace `setAnimation()` with `startAnimation()` and call it after `setVisibility()`

Now it works fine on all devices , even disconnected from the debugger !

Answer (score 2):

use `startAnimation()` instead of `setAnimation()` and call it  after `setVisibility()`

Comment: I tried your suggestion , it works as well like setAnimation() , which means don't work on my nexus 5 api 23 :(

Comment: I just tried it on my htc desire 530 (API 23) and it's working just fine, guess something else is causing the problem. @ismailalaoui

Comment: I didn't find what's wrong with it really , just as information,  the animation is on a textview on an alertdialog !